# Add a hover effect on unoredered list

Tags: javascript, css

```css
body{
background: #080808;
color: #fff;
}
#header{
width: 100%;
height: 100vh;
background-image: url();
background-position: center;
background-size: cover;
padding-bottom: 50


 }
.container{
padding: 10px 10% ;
}

nav{
display: flex;
align-items: center;
justify-content: space-between;
flex-wrap: wrap;

}

.logo{
width: 140px;
}

 nav ul li{
display: inline-block;
list-style: none;
margin: 10px 20px;
}

nav ul li a{
position: relative;
text-decoration: none;
color: #fff;
}

nav ul li a::after{
content: "";
position: absolute;
bottom: -6px;
left: 0;
width: 0;
height: 3px;
background-color: red;


}

nav ul li a:hover::after{
width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
        <nav>
            <img src="" class="logo">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#Home"></a>Home</li>
                <li><a href="#About"></a>About</li>
                <li><a href="#Services"></a>Services</li>
                <li><a href="#Portfolio"></a>Portfolio</li>
                <li><a href="#Contact"></a>Contact</li>
            </ul>
         </nav>
       </div>
```

I want to add a hover effect to the ul li but the code seems not to work.

I think this is how it should be but the css seems not to work for some reason. Thanks anyways
I also tried using the opacity tag but it still doesn't work.
Edit: I have now edit the HTML Code. The problem is that the hover effect doen't appear.
**What I want** is to make a hover effect for the ul li.

Comment: Please, add the HMTL code.

Comment: Please describe what the problem is, what you want to happen versus what does happen. And make a runnable snippet so we can see for ourselves. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: There's no problem in **CSS** code. Provide HTML Code

Comment: I have provided the HTML code. Please look at it.

Comment: Please make your code into a runnable snippet.

Comment: I have added the snippet and as you can that it should have hover effect(red lines appearing when we hover over it) but it doesn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you have to put the text **inside** the a tags

```css
body{
background: #080808;
color: #fff;
}
#header{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background-image: url();
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  padding-bottom: 50
 }
.container{
  padding: 10px 10% ;
}

nav{
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.logo{
  width: 140px;
}

nav ul li{
  display: inline-block;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 10px 20px;
}

nav ul li a{
  position: relative;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
}

nav ul li a::after{
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -6px;
  left: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 3px;
  background-color: red;
  transition-duration: 300ms;
}

nav ul li a:hover::after{
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#Home">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#About">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="#Services">Services</a></li>
      <li><a href="#Portfolio">Portfolio</a></li>
      <li><a href="#Contact">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```